# Find a pattern in a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to detect a string inside the following pattern: `[url('example')]` in order to replace the value.

I thought of using a regex to get the strings inside the squared brackets and then another to get the text inside the parenthesis but I am not sure if that's the best way to do it.

```
//detect all strings inside brackets
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $text, $matches);

//loop though results to get the string inside the parenthesis
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $match, $matches);
```

Comment: Try this: `(?<=\[url\(')[^']+(?='\)\])`

Answer (score 1):

To match the string between the parenthesis, you might use a single pattern to get a match only:

```
\[url\(\K[^()]+(?=\)])
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[url\(` Match `[url(`
- `\K` Clear the current match buffer
- `[^()]+` Match 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(?=\)])` Positive lookahead, assert `)]` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8QSYGY/1).

For example

```
$re = "/\[url\(\K[^()]+(?=\)])/";
$text = "[url('example')]";
if (preg_match($re, $text, $match)) {
    var_dump($match[0]);;
}
```

Output

```
string(9) "'example'"
```

---

Another option could be using a capture group. You can place the `'` inside or outside the group to capture the value:

```
\[url\(([^()]+)\)]
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxNtTB/1).

For example

```
$re = "/\[url\(([^()]+)\)]/";
$text = "[url('example')]";
if (preg_match($re, $text, $match)) {
    var_dump($match[1]);;
}
```

Output

```
string(9) "'example'"
```